# What is the meaning of this passage?

Tags: grammar

I started reading a practice reading for N3 yesterday, and found this passage in a sentence that is very confusing

他人から見れば「**どうしてそんなことを」というような**ことをしてしまう親のことである。

If someone can help me I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide additional context, and/or make sure it's typed correctly?  I'm no expert but the bolded passage seems ungrammatical/confusing to me.

Comment: Thank you for remarking that, I hadn't noticed the lack of parentheses and the fact that I didn't type the word「こと」。すみません

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「するの?」is omitted at the end of 「どうしてそんなことを」. It means "Why do you do such a thing?"

My attempt is as follows. This is about parents who end up doing something like others say, "Why do you do such a thing?"